# subquery results appends to all main query selected field

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, json-query, scalar-subquery

I'm writing a stored procedure to get list of IOT parameter data under a specific machine and the result of stored procedure should have a specific JSON format. the problem is, when I tried to add a parameter data under another machine I found out the subquery result append all its results under all machines. I want to Alter the query so each machine should have just its parameter data under it and not changing the JSON format.

This is the Stored procedure:

```
declare @jsonTwo nvarchar(max)=(
Select JSON_QUERY((
select CAST((
select 
MAE.MachineName as MachineName
, 
(select IOTR.MachineCode, IOTP.IotParameterName, IOTR.CreatedAt, datename(WEEKDAY, IOTR.CreatedAt) as FilterRange, 
avg(IOTP.IotParameterValue) as ParameterValue,MP.UpperControlLimit , MP.LowerControlLimit
from IOTMachineParameters IOTP 
inner join IOTMachineReadings IOTR ON IOTP.IotMachineID = IOTR.Id
inner join MachineAndEquipments MAE on MAE.MachineCode = IOTR.MachineCode
inner join MachineParameters MP on IOTP.IotParameterName = MP.ParamterName
where 
MP.ParameterType = 'PARAMETERIZED' 
and IotP.IsChecked = 1 
and IOTR.CompanyCode = 'DA-1663079927040'
and MAE.MachineCode = IOTR.MachineCode
and IOTP.IotMachineID = IOTR.Id
and IOTR.CreatedAt >= '2022-09-01' and IOTR.CreatedAt <= '2022-11-16 10:11:00.0000000'
group by IOTR.MachineCode,IOTP.IotParameterName,IOTR.CreatedAt,datename(WEEKDAY, IOTR.CreatedAt),MAE.MachineName,MP.LowerControlLimit,MP.UpperControlLimit
 for json path) as MachineReadings
from  MachineAndEquipments MAE inner join IOTMachineReadings IOTR ON MAE.MachineCode = IOTR.MachineCode
inner join IOTMachineParameters IOTP ON IOTP.IotMachineID = IOTR.Id
where MAE.CompanyId = 'DA-1663079927040'
and IOTP.IotMachineID = IOTR.Id
group by MAE.MachineName
 for json path ,Include_null_values)as nvarchar(max))as part1 for json path, without_array_wrapper)));
select @jsonTwo as data
```

when i run the MachineReadings subquery it returns all the records
[reults of MachineReadings subquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzLH9.png)
The tables are:
[Tables of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpih1.png)
so is there a way to like filter out the subquery results based on the outer selection of Machine Name.

I expected each object, has Machine name and a list of IOT parameter reading data under this machine name only. Instead I found that each Machine name has the same exact list of IOT parameter reading data

Targeted JSON format:

```
{
   "part1":[
      {
         "MachineName":"Machine X",
         "MachineReadings":[
            {
               "MachineCode":"Machine-012",
               "MachineName":"Machine X",
               "IotParameterName":"t",
               "CreatedAt":"2022-11-14T11:11:42",
               "FilterRange":"Monday",
               "ParameterValue":20.000000,
               "UpperControlLimit":0.00,
               "LowerControlLimit":0.00
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "MachineName":"Machine Y",
         "MachineReadings":[            
            {
               "MachineCode":"Machine-789",
               "MachineName":"Machine Y",
               "IotParameterName":"a test",
               "CreatedAt":"2022-11-16T10:11:00",
               "FilterRange":"Wednesday",
               "ParameterValue":3.000000,
               "UpperControlLimit":0.00,
               "LowerControlLimit":0.00
            },
            {
               "MachineCode":"Machine-789",
               "MachineName":"Machine Y",
               "IotParameterName":"new parameter",
               "CreatedAt":"2022-11-15T10:09:51",
               "FilterRange":"Tuesday",
               "ParameterValue":13.500000,
               "UpperControlLimit":0.00,
               "LowerControlLimit":0.00
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

This is The Resulted JSON Format:

```
{
   "part1":[
      {
         "MachineName":"rtyy",
         "MachineCode":"Machine-012",
         "MachineReadings":[
            {
               "MachineCode":"Machine-012",
               "MachineName":"rtyy",
               "IotParameterName":"t",
               "CreatedAt":"2022-11-14T11:11:42",
               "FilterRange":"Monday",
               "ParameterValue":20.000000,
               "UpperControlLimit":0.00,
               "LowerControlLimit":0.00
            },
            {
               "MachineCode":"Machine-789",
               "MachineName":"the other 789",
               "IotParameterName":"a test",
               "CreatedAt":"2022-11-16T10:11:00",
               "FilterRange":"Wednesday",
               "ParameterValue":3.000000,
               "UpperControlLimit":0.00,
               "LowerControlLimit":0.00
            },
            {
               "MachineCode":"Machine-789",
               "MachineName":"the other 789",
               "IotParameterName":"new parameter",
               "CreatedAt":"2022-11-15T10:09:51",
               "FilterRange":"Tuesday",
               "ParameterValue":13.500000,
               "UpperControlLimit":0.00,
               "LowerControlLimit":0.00
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "MachineName":"the other 789",
         "MachineCode":"Machine-789",
         "MachineReadings":[
            {
               "MachineCode":"Machine-012",
               "MachineName":"rtyy",
               "IotParameterName":"t",
               "CreatedAt":"2022-11-14T11:11:42",
               "FilterRange":"Monday",
               "ParameterValue":20.000000,
               "UpperControlLimit":0.00,
               "LowerControlLimit":0.00
            },
            {
               "MachineCode":"Machine-789",
               "MachineName":"the other 789",
               "IotParameterName":"a test",
               "CreatedAt":"2022-11-16T10:11:00",
               "FilterRange":"Wednesday",
               "ParameterValue":3.000000,
               "UpperControlLimit":0.00,
               "LowerControlLimit":0.00
            },
            {
               "MachineCode":"Machine-789",
               "MachineName":"the other 789",
               "IotParameterName":"new parameter",
               "CreatedAt":"2022-11-15T10:09:51",
               "FilterRange":"Tuesday",
               "ParameterValue":13.500000,
               "UpperControlLimit":0.00,
               "LowerControlLimit":0.00
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be there's no relationship between the correlated subquery `MachineReadings` and tables in outer query `FROM` clause. Thus, the result of `MachineReadings` is applied to every row returned by outer query.

Formatted your code below for easy reference:

```
declare @jsonTwo nvarchar(max)=(
Select
    JSON_QUERY((
    select
        CAST((
        select
            MAE.MachineName as MachineName
,
            (
            select
                IOTR.MachineCode,
                IOTP.IotParameterName,
                IOTR.CreatedAt,
                datename(WEEKDAY, IOTR.CreatedAt) as FilterRange,
                avg(IOTP.IotParameterValue) as ParameterValue,
                MP.UpperControlLimit ,
                MP.LowerControlLimit
            from
                IOTMachineParameters IOTP
            inner join IOTMachineReadings IOTR ON
                IOTP.IotMachineID = IOTR.Id
            inner join MachineAndEquipments MAE on
                MAE.MachineCode = IOTR.MachineCode
            inner join MachineParameters MP on
                IOTP.IotParameterName = MP.ParamterName
            where
                MP.ParameterType = 'PARAMETERIZED'
                and IotP.IsChecked = 1
                and IOTR.CompanyCode = 'DA-1663079927040'
                and MAE.MachineCode = IOTR.MachineCode
                and IOTP.IotMachineID = IOTR.Id
                and IOTR.CreatedAt >= '2022-09-01'
                and IOTR.CreatedAt <= '2022-11-16 10:11:00.0000000'
            group by
                IOTR.MachineCode,
                IOTP.IotParameterName,
                IOTR.CreatedAt,
                datename(WEEKDAY, IOTR.CreatedAt),
                MAE.MachineName,
                MP.LowerControlLimit,
                MP.UpperControlLimit
 for json path) as MachineReadings
        from
            MachineAndEquipments MAE
        inner join IOTMachineReadings IOTR ON
            MAE.MachineCode = IOTR.MachineCode
        inner join IOTMachineParameters IOTP ON
            IOTP.IotMachineID = IOTR.Id
        where
            MAE.CompanyId = 'DA-1663079927040'
            and IOTP.IotMachineID = IOTR.Id
        group by
            MAE.MachineName
 for json path ,
            Include_null_values)as nvarchar(max))as part1 for json path,
        without_array_wrapper)));
select @jsonTwo as data
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the query to make the relation between the subquery and outer query and at the same time keep the target JSON format as it's.

Comment: @dode it would be helpful if you could share some samples data in dbfiddle.uk, so that the community can involve easily.